# Graphing a graph with different colors in matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, graph

I have the following table.

```
  Date       Score
11-01-02      40
11-01-03      47
11-01-04      41
11-01-05      35
11-01-06      52
11-01-07      47
11-01-08      45
11-01-09      43
11-01-10      40
11-01-11      41
11-01-12      41
11-01-13      49
11-01-14      40
11-01-15      40
```

I read it as a pandas file in python, and I would like to graph it as a line graph so that the scores BEFORE 2011/01/08 have yellow color, and whatever is on 2011/01/08 or after have the red color on the same axes.

Is it possible in python? I know how to do it in R, but I'm not sure if there's a similar function in pandas.

Comment: Ok so same line different colors. I guess we need to create two lines and merge them. You know how to do it in R? Why not share that knowledge then?

Comment: @AntonvBR  i didn't merge them in R. At the point the color shifted, the line is not connected. Sorry that I didn't clarify that part. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gave this an attempt that someone else can possibly continue with as the lines are not connected after the groupby.

The workaround is to use another mask that is inbetween those dates.

Anyway, full example below:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

csvdata = '''\
Date          Score
11-01-02      40
11-01-03      47
11-01-04      41
11-01-05      35
11-01-06      52
11-01-07      47
11-01-08      45
11-01-09      43
11-01-10      40
11-01-11      41
11-01-12      41
11-01-13      49
11-01-14      40
11-01-15      40'''

# Recreate data and convert Date to datetime
fileobj = pd.compat.StringIO(csvdata)
df = pd.read_csv(fileobj, sep='\s+')
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], yearfirst=True)

# Based on the date provided by OP, either RED or YELLOW to col Color
cond = df.Date >= '2011-01-08'
df['Color'] = np.where(cond, 'RED', 'YELLOW')

# Create the frame 
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,6))

# Fill the frame with data (note: missing datapoint!)
for color, dfx in df.groupby('Color'):
   dfx.plot(x='Date', y='Score', color=color, ax=ax) 

# The workaround --> does not feel reliable for consistant use though.
m1 = df['Date'].between('2011-01-07', '2011-01-08')
df[m1].plot(x='Date',y='Score', color=df['Color'], ax=ax)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Another way would be to plot the conditional part on top of the whole curve:

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv("test.txt", delim_whitespace = True)
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date, format = '%y-%m-%d')
#define cutoff date
cutoff = "2011-01-08"
#sort dataframe because unsorted dates will not plot properly
df = df.sort_values(["Date"])
#plot the whole dataframe in yellow
plt.plot(df.Date, df.Score, c = "y", label = "before {}".format(cutoff))
#plot the conditional data on top in red
plt.plot(df[df.Date >= cutoff].Date, df[df.Date >= cutoff].Score, c = "r", label = "after {}".format(cutoff))
plt.xticks(rotation = 45)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]